# How can I render 3 elements per loop in django template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I don't know how to express my need.I just show the code.

```
data_lis = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

How can I separate this list into `N` parts with 3 element each part?

I do this is in order to render

```
<div class="card-group d-block d-md-flex u-card--gutters-2-md">
<div class="card border-0 rounded shadow-sm mb-3 transition-3d-hover">element</div>
<div class="card border-0 rounded shadow-sm mb-3 transition-3d-hover">element</div>
<div class="card border-0 rounded shadow-sm mb-3 transition-3d-hover">element</div>
</div>
```

I need to render the data just like the above style,but how can I dynamically change the render way？

#### My solutions

```
a = [
   [3,2,3],
   [3,4,2],
   [3,2]
]
```

I just handly separate it into `N` parts with 3 elements each part!

Comment: `print( [data_lis[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(data_lis), 3)] )`

Comment: @Rakesh  Thanks for your help,but I just want to know whether It can solve in django template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use syntax Rakesh said

```
data_list = [data_list[i:min(i+3, len(data_list)] for i in xrange(0, len(data_list_, 3)]
```

also you can change your syntax in your template like this

```
{% for i in a %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}
    <div class="card-group d-block d-md-flex u-card--gutters-2-md">
    {% endif %}
        <div class="card border-0 rounded shadow-sm mb-3 transition-3d-hover">
             {{ k }} 
        </div>        
    {% if forloop.counter0|add:2|divisibleby:3 %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% ifequal a|length|divisibleby:3 False %}
    </div>
{% endifnotequal %}
```

and here you dont want to split content to list of lists.

Comment: change one syntax error.`{% endifequal %}`、 `{% if forloop.counter0|add:-2|divisibleby:3 %}` would work.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you need the template syntax.

**Try:**

```
{% for i in a %}
    <div class="card-group d-block d-md-flex u-card--gutters-2-md">
    {% for k in i %}        
            <div class="card border-0 rounded shadow-sm mb-3 transition-3d-hover">{{ k }}</div>        
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

To divide the list to N chunks use.

```
data_lis = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
N = 3
a =  [data_lis[i:i+N] for i in range(0, len(data_lis), N)] 
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```